# iOS Autolayout: two views of equal width and equally spaced

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard, ios-autolayout

I am currently having difficulty with AutoLayout. I am using interface builder and am trying to place two uiview blocks of 100 * 100. I need these blocks placed in such a way that 1st block's leading to superview equals to 2nd block's trailing to superview.Further this equals to space between these two blocks and equally changes as per screen width.
I have tried using stackview
[giving fixed width to stackview seems to be equally spaced in 4s but not on 6s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsrgc.png).Keeping width not fixed results in greater spacing in between blocks [as here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQAkG.png) .

Does it is possible to achieve this through interface builder?
Great thanks for any help.

Comment: Should the height and width of the views inside the stackview change or they should remain fixed to some predetermined values?

Comment: Yes, this block width n height is constant 100 from 4s to 6s plus.For ipad this values is to be changed to 150.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IB doesn't handle this very gracefully. The kludgy solution is to add "spacer" views (views that we'll add for the sake of spacing in autolayout, but which will be invisible). Just make the spacer views widths equal and then either drop these five views in a stack view or just set up horizontal constraints so the five views abut each other:

[image]

Then, just set the spacer views background to clear color, so we don't see them, and you'll have the spacing you want:

[image]

---

If doing this programmatically (which I know you're not doing, but just for the sake of completeness), you'd use [`UILayoutGuide`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilayoutguide) rather than these invisible spacer views:

```
let view1 = ...
let view2 = ...

let layout1 = UILayoutGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(layout1)
let layout2 = UILayoutGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(layout2)
let layout3 = UILayoutGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(layout3)

let views: [String: Any] = ["view1": view1, "view2": view2, "layout1": layout1, "layout2": layout2, "layout3": layout3]

view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[layout1][view1(==100)][layout2(==layout1)][view2(==100)][layout3(==layout1)]|", options: .alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views))

view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-[view1(==100)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-[view2(==100)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
```

It's somewhat amazing that Apple still hasn't added layout guides to IB, yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob.I used spacer view solution.